# clean up trash in elementary OS 0.4 Loki

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files

How to look for the trash and clean them up in elementary OS 0.4 Loki?

Answer (score 2):

What trash are you speaking of? If you mean items in your trash folder, just delete them.

If you mean files/libraries that are no longer needed you can run

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

you can also install bleachbit to clear up lingering "junk" files

```
sudo apt install bleachbit
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the Trash in *Pantheon Files* via `trash:///` or the sidebar icon trash.

You can empty it by right-clicking on the icon and selecting *Empty Trash* from the menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the `trash-cli` package

```
sudo apt install trash-cli
```

To list files run the following command:

```
trash-list
```

To clean up the trash run:

```
trash-empty
```

To remove files that have been to trash for `N` days run :

```
trash-empty N
```

Also you can use it as root.